# Joystick/Gamepad not working in RetroArch

Tags: peripherals, emulation

I've installed RetroArch following [these instructions](http://www.raspberrypilabs.com/retroarch-in-raspberry-pi-snes), and I would like to use my gamepad.

I'm using a USB connector for my GameCube controller, and I'm running the pocketsnes emulator. The emulator runs fine (sound is kind of terrible), and the games play fine with the keyboard.

I've configured the gamepad with `retroarch-joyconfig`, and the joystick seems to be operating correctly, as it registers my button presses and analog stick movements.

However, when I start up a game, the gamepad doesn't do anything, and I have to control the game with the keyboard.

Are there any additional steps I should take to get the gamepad working?

Also, is there a ways to skip mappings for certain buttons in the `retroarch-joyconfig` tool. It has configuration for 3 shoulder buttons and I've mapped them all to the same 2 shoulder buttons.

Could this be causing a problem?

Comment: What does dmesg say?

Comment: Don't know, but it's not a problem with the device.  works just fine entering the keymappings and I've used it for FCEU and it worked fine (although FCEU runs too slowly). I'm assuming its some kind of issue with retroarch not even looking at the gamepad for whatever reason.

Comment: running "dmesg | grep hid" shows that the gamepad is picked up properly. It shows as "generic-usb 003:05E3:0681.0001: input,hiddev0: USB HID v1.00 Joystick [Austgame GameCube to USB convertor] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was using retroarch-joyconfig improperly.  retroarch-joyconfig simply outputs the settings that need to be placed in the config file to standard out after you have completed entering the mappings. You need to take that standard output and put it in the config file. The config file needs to be at `~/.retroarch.cfg`.  If you don't have a config file, you probably won't have one yet, which is fine. If you have one, you may want to back it up to avoid losing your settings, even though you are just appending to the file.  Backup the (possibly) existing file with the following command

```
cp ~/.retroarch.cfg ~/.retroarch.cfg.old
```

Type the following at the command prompt to run retroarch-joyconfig and append the settings to the `~/.retroarch.cfg` file.

```
retroarch-joyconfig >> ~/.retroarch.cfg
```

Press the buttons to enter the mappings as prompted, and when it completes you will have the required settings in your `~/.retroarch.cfg` file.

Comment: This doesn't address skipping control mappings. What are we supposed to do about those?

Comment: @AbeFehr Sounds like you have a completely different problem. Try posting a new question.